# wildfly swarm: lookup ejb remote interface

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, microservices, wildfly-swarm

I have generated two simple wildfly swarm projects. First has EJB facade with Remote interface, second should lookup it and send message. So second should be as client.

I am used
Wildfly swarm version 2017.9.4

My EJB facade lookup paths:

```
        java:global/ejb-one/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote
        java:app/ejb-one/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote
        java:module/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote
        java:jboss/exported/ejb-one/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote
        java:global/ejb-one/PingFacade
        java:app/ejb-one/PingFacade
        java:module/PingFacade
```

My client :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackendConnectionManager manager = new BackendConnectionManager();
        try {
            manager.getPingFacadeRemote().savePingMessage("halloooooo");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BackendConnectionManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public  PingFacadeRemote getPingFacadeRemote() throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
              jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
                 //jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http://localhost:8080");
        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        return (PingFacadeRemote) context
                .lookup("java:global/ejb-one/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote");
    }
```

Added client dependencies to pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-remote</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-naming</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-api</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.remoting3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.sasl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-sasl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I do not what is whole dependencies for client and always has

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is org.jboss.remoting3.ServiceOpenException: Unknown service name]
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.getRemoteTransport(RemoteContext.java:80)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:106)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:150)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:150)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at io.project.ejbtwo.rest.BackendConnectionManager.getPingFacadeRemote(BackendConnectionManager.java:57)
    at io.project.ejbtwo.rest.BackendConnectionManager.main(BackendConnectionManager.java:43)
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting3.ServiceOpenException: Unknown service name
```

Also how to solve problem with passing security credentials in client lookup?

Projects by itself here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B45Md1_c5-gGQ0p3Q2pURUxOY00

Comment: Could you provide the version of WildFly server you used and the steps to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 1):

In **BackendConnectionManager.java**, line 57, you are trying to look up the service `java:global/ejb-one/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote`, but it seems to not exist. `PingFacadeRemote` interface is a part of `ejb-core` module. Yes, it is true that you implement it in `ejb-one` module, but you registered the interface as a remote (`@Remote(PingFacadeRemote.class)`, in **PingFacade.java**).

You might try to replace it with `java:global/ejb-core/PingFacade!io.project.core.interfaces.PingFacadeRemote`.